# custom function that add geoms to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to plot a lot of histograms (one for each variable in the dataset) that look like this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = var)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(4, 16, 1), limits = c(4, 16)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(var)), color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(var)), color="blue", size=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=quantile(var,0.25)), color="green", linetype="dotted", size=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=quantile(var,0.75)), color="green", linetype="dotted", size=1)
```

The only think that changes is bindwidth, breaks and limits.
Can I code a custom function in R that adds all these geom_vline to any plot and avoid the boilerplate?

Something like:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = var)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(4, 16, 1), limits = c(4, 16)) +
  stat_lines(df, var)
```

I tried just returning the concatenation of all geom_vline but I get:

```
Error in df[, var] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addGeomVline<-function(plot,...){
plot+geom_vline(...)
}
```

Here is an example about how to use it

```
p<-qplot(x=1:3,y=1:3)
addGeomVline(p,xintercept = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess is a different question, but: how can I access the column used for the x axis? So I do not need to pass it as an argument. I tried with plot$mapping$x but it does not work, apparently it is just a symbol, not the data column...

Comment: Access it do what?

Comment: So I can use for example the mean for the xintercept, not some fixed value.

Comment: plot$data[,as.character(plot$mapping[["x"]])]

Comment: Does not work. I think it is because it does not have access to the local environment. Also tried with plot$data[,plot$labels$x]. This is what I am trying to do: http://pastebin.com/q8dfSyJ1 It says "Error in plot$data : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" with your method too...